# Existence of Functional with some Functional Derivative

Tags: homework-and-exercises, action, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

How could I do this? I tried to manipulate, but I don't know how I could get to a contradiction or something else.

> Show that there is no functional $S = S[\phi]$ that satisfies: (where $\epsilon_{ij}$ is Levi-Civita symbol)
>   $$\dfrac{\delta S[\phi]}{\delta \phi} = \epsilon_{ij}(\partial_i \phi)(\partial_j \partial^2 \phi).$$

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301)

Comment: This question was only a few close votes short of a full migration to [math.se]. Note that the [Phys.SE community usually welcomes math questions relevant for physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5713/2451). I closed it as H&E partly to buy the Phys.SE community more time to decide what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: In order for an expression $E(x)$ to be a [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) $$\exists S:~~E(x)~\stackrel{?}{=}~\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(x)},\tag{1}$$
it must satisfy an integrability condition, namely a functional [Maxwell relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations)
$$ \frac{\delta E(x)}{\delta\phi(y)}~=~\frac{\delta E(y)}{\delta\phi(x)}.\tag{2}$$
This is because functional derivatives commute
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(x)}\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(y)}~=~\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(y)}\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(x)}.\tag{3}$$
Conversely, if the integrability condition (2) is violated then the functional $S$ in eq. (1) cannot exist.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But why two functional derivatives necessarily has to commute? Doesn't we have an extra assumption for that to happen? Like in partial derivatives; the derivatives doesn't need to commute, unless the function is C².

Comment: In physics it is usually implicitly assumed that functions are sufficiently nice, but in principle you're right.